# parsing script isnt putting out

Tags: php, parsing, screen-scraping

```
<?

$file = "http://www.google.com";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
echo @$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($file));


$element = $doc->getElementsbyTagName('span');



echo trim($element->item(0)->nodeValue);
echo trim($element->item(0)->textContent);

if (!is_null($element)) {
        $content = $element->nodeValue;

        if (empty($content)) {
            $content = $element->textContent;


           }

            echo $content . "\n";
        }

?>
```

i am trying to test this script and am wondering why can't i parse google?  if you look into the source page, hit ctrl+f type in span there is obviously a span tag.  why isn't it giving me results??

Comment: Have you tried outputting the HTML in the DOMDocument? `var_dump($doc->saveHTML());` to see whether it contains what you think it contanis?

Comment: Did you try buying it dinner??

Comment: @RutgersMike, I wondered if anyone would comment related to the title.

Comment: @davidethell usually 'no' means 'no' =oP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$file = 'http://www.google.com';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@ $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($file));

$element = $doc->getElementsByTagName('span');

if (0 != $element->length) 
{
    $content = trim($element->item(0)->nodeValue);
    if (empty($content)) 
    {
        $content = trim($element->item(0)->textContent);
    }
    echo $content . "\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Your value for $file was wrong, you were specifying $DOCUMENT_ROOT and then putting the URL to Google, so I changed it to just the URL to Google and also changed loadHTMLFile() to loadHTML() where it will use the contents fetched by file_get_contents() thus Google's HTML.

Comment: if i echo out  @$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($file)); it returns "1", but as for getting it to search through the dom nodes, no go. .

Comment: You should turn error_reporting to E_ALL because I don't think you have it on since the above would generate errors for you otherwise.

Comment: the only error is you forgot 'by' in getElementsTageName haha, right.. ?

Comment: I didn't forget anything, I never changed that line from your original code. Btw don't use the @ to supress errors when developing, otherwise you will miss important errors. I'm trying to debug your code so be back in a few mins.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I recommend a parsing lib like phpquery or simple_html_dom

Comment: I tested it and it outputs the value "Google Instant is unavailable. Press Enter to search." which is the contents of the 1st SPAN tag on the Google homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but doesnt allow_url_fopen need to be enabled in php.ini for this to work?

code removed

Comment: allow_url_fopen is not a function its a PHP directive, so why are you using function_exists() on it?

Comment: just a suggestion, i guess im incorrect. seemed to work in my testing. doesnt that directive need to be enabled though?